# python compare items in 2 list of different length and sequence/ duplicates should be considered

Tags: list, python-3.x

I'm trying to compare two lists of unequal length

```
list1=['a','b','d','b','c','d','e','f']
list2=['a','b','d','d']
```

list1 should be compared until the last element in list2(which is 'd') is found in list1.
Below is the desired output

```
output = ['b','c']
```

below is the code which i have

```
i = 0 
j = 0
output = []
while(True):
    if(list1[i] == list2[j]):
        i += 1
        j += 1
        if (j == len(list2)):
            break
    else:
        output.append(list1[i])
        i = i + 1
```

is there any better way of doing the same?

Thanks for helping!

Comment: how do you compare to get your output `['b','c']` ?

Comment: Also, how does the loop end? Will the lists not throw an IndexError?

Comment: Why not `['b','c', 'e', 'f']`?

Comment: Have given the code which i have in the question.. Loop ends when the last element of list2 is found in list1 . Comparision should be made till second 'd' from list2 is found in list1

Answer (score 3):

I think you want `itertools.takewhile`

```
from itertools import takewhile

def taker(l1, l2):
    it = iter(l1)
    for j in l2:
        yield from takewhile(lambda x: x!=j, it)
```

`list(taker(list1, list2))` is `['b', 'c']`

Comment: Subtle, but the side effect of advancing the iterator `it` and discarding on equal is exactly fitting for this problem.